# How to run all Golang benchmark tests including subfolders

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, benchmarking

I have a Go application with a number of unit and benchmark tests both in the root and in a subfolder called "message".

I execute the following command to run all unit tests from the root including the ones in the messages and any other subfolder:

```
go test ./...
```

I want to achieve the same for the benchmark tests, i.e. run them all. The following works for the ones in the root directory:

```
go test -bench .
```

The benchmark tests in the /messages folder are ignored which is expected. So I run the following from the root:

```
go test -bench ./...
```

That's not recognised at all, Go seems to execute the **unit tests** that are located in the root dir. I even tried to specify the message folder in the command as follows:

```
go test -bench ./message
```

...but it also failed. Currently if I want to run the benchmark tests in the message folder I have to cd into that folder and execute

```
go test -bench .
```

like above.

So what's the correct way then? How can I tell Go to find the benchmark tests both in the root and the subfolders? How does the regexp arg work in the case of the -bench flag? Apparently it's different from the regexp for the unit test runner.

Comment: Have you tried `go test ./... -bench`? Or `go test -bench=. ./...`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `./...` to bench all the files from the current working directory and all of its subdirectories. If you wish to get a more verbose output you can use the `-v` flag. Also it's good to list the memory allocation by using `-benchmem`.

```
go test -v ./... -bench=. -run=xxx -benchmem
```

Answer (score 3):

[`-bench` flag](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags) takes regex so to run all benchmarks (`-bench .`) in all packages: `go test -bench=. ./...`